# Android How to Exit a Runnable Loop with postDelayed

Tags: java, android, loops, runnable, postdelayed

I am having a problem trying to loop a runnable with a delay. I basically want to change the background of a sequence of 8 textviews with a second of interval in between each changes. The code below works fine but I can't seem to exit the runnable, the code gets stuck and wont execute anything below it. Any tips on how to make this work? Thanks.

```
    final Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        final Integer i = j + 1;
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int resid = getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", getPackageName());
                TextView scales_text = (TextView) findViewById(resid);
                scales_text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_select);
            }
        }, (1000) * j);
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *the code gets stuck and wont execute anything below it*?

Comment: Essentially, the code will not execute anything else below that piece I posted. It seems like it stays in the run() void and wont continue to run anything else. For example, if I put:

        System.out.print("END");

below the above, nothing will print on the console. Thanks.

Comment: I find your statement hard to believe. Did you check the logcat for errors/crashes? (don't filter the logcat, you might miss something).

Comment: Ok I think I understand the problem, the code below does get executed but at the same time as the runnable. However, I would like this to be so AFTER the loop has ended (essentially after the 8 seconds are up). Is there a way to do this? Thanks.